# Return Map<Key, Value> with condition in Hibernate Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-annotations

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id, target (string), audience_group_id, rating (Integer), job_id
```

`target` column is a string representation of one of the following values:
predicted, actual, updated

I thought to add method in Job class:

`Map<AudienceGroup, Integer( this it the rating)> getAudienceRatingPerPredictedPrograms()`.

I am stuck with the annotation. How can I tell it to return map that the value in target is "predicted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am stuck with the annotation. How can I tell it to return map that the value in target is "predicted"?

*If* this is doable (I have some doubts about the table design, this will require some testing), I think you'll have to use the `Map` annotations (`@org.hibernate.annotations.MapKey/MapKeyManyToMany`) in conjunction with Hibernate's [filtering](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters) capabilities to filter the association.

I would first try to map the `Map` as wanted (probably using `MapKeyManyToMany` in your case). Once done with the `Map`, apply the filter.

I've never tested this.

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations 3.4 Reference Guide

  - [2.2.5.3. Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-collections)
  - [2.4.6.2.2. Map](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-map)
  - [2.4.9. Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters)